# Adding html codes to SharePoint Online

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

is it possible to add html codes to SharePoint Online?
I would like to add a html code from Statista such as the following:

```html
<a href="https://www.statista.com/statistics/262861/uk-brent-crude-oil-monthly-price-development/" rel="nofollow"><img src="https://www.statista.com/graphic/1/262861/uk-brent-crude-oil-monthly-price-development.jpg" alt="Statistic: Average monthly Brent crude oil price from July 2018 to July 2019 (in U.S. dollars per barrel)* | Statista" style="width: 100%; height: auto !important; max-width:1000px;-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;"/></a><br />Find more statistics at  <a href="https://www.statista.com" rel="nofollow">Statista</a>
```

As far as I know only iframe based codes can get entered to SP Online. However, Statista only provides the above mentioned version.
Is there any possibility to add these codes to SP Online?
Please note that I am really not familiar with such codes.`

Thanks in advance
Markus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not supported to add html codes in SharePoint modern page. However, you could achieve this in classic page.

Go to Pages library, create a classic page.Click Edit Source in the ribbon and add the code.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Only way you can do this OTB is by saving your HTML code as a .aspx page, uploading it into a document library and then using the 'Embed' webpart.

terribly annoying as you have to edit your code separately, but this will allow any/all completely custom code (HTML/CSS/JS) to be inserted into the page.

Answer (score 0):

We can deploy [react script editor web part](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor) to your site, then add the HTML code into this web part in modern site page. In classic site page, we can use the OOTB script editor web part to achieve it.

[image]

Answer (score -4):

If you have a standard Sharepoint page - click the add button to add a new element and then select "Code Snippet". You can then paste the code there. You may run into some permission issues depending on your setup however.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. However, this only shows the code on the SharePoint page but does not transfer it to the image I would like to display. Is there a possibility to not only show the code but to show the actual content?

Comment: @markus By my means you can't. Because of cross site scripting hacks. Sharepoint allows you to insert HTML but not javascript from other origins like statista which will build your statics, just for security reasons. Only iframe codes could be added, but if statista does not allow to use iframes your stuck here

Comment: What a pitty. But thanks a lot for the prompt reply.

Comment: @Pikapops It looks, this answer is outdated.. Keep it updated with latest solution for the same..